# NSURL Connection Warning "Unused variable"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting data from an NSURL connection like below. The code works, but I get a compiler warning that says "Unused variable strResult."

**I don't actually need to use what is returned. I just need the URL to be executed.**

How can I go about modifying this to get rid of the warning?

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.site.com/file.php?id=%@", id];

NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the `strResult` anywhere after declaring ie the Warning . 
Just log it you can see the warning goes off.

```
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

Comment: Thanks! - Wow, got blasted for this question

Answer (score 3):

You have initialized and assigned data in `strResult` variable but you haven't used that variable.

So use that variable or just `NSLog@("%@",strResult)`

i suggest if the variable is not useful then remove that variable it occupies memory

Comment: Thanks for the idea! works perfectly - thought I was supposed to be executing the URL differently.

Comment: If you think that strResult is not useful variable in your app then remove that

Answer (score 2):

use `NSURLConnection` and call it's static method:

```
[NSURLConnction sendSynchronousRequest:.....]
```

and if you wanna send Asynchronous request use:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronusRequest:....]
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler just informs you that you created a variable and you are not using it (yet) .. so  the best solution is to use it, as a return value of your method. It would help to see the complete implementation of the relevant method to help you better.

Hope this clarifies the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You get that warning, because nowhere in your code, you actually use `strResult`.

Use it, and the warning is gone :) Or, remove the statement if you don't actually need the repsonse.

Comment: I don't actually need to use what is returned. I just need the URL to be executed.